# How to implement AVCam using Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, avcam

[This sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) covers implementation only for ios11.

Can someone provide some example and/or hints for me to understand and code further?

Answer (score 0):

I found a repo where version 6.1 of AVCam was commited before 7.1

https://github.com/Lax/iOS-Swift-Demos

here's the state of the repo on the commit for version 6.1 (Xcode 8.0, iOS 10.0)
https://github.com/Lax/iOS-Swift-Demos/tree/2a92c00b6d800165f29be6a525b5e98424bc5843

It's a shame Apple doesn't make it easier to access previous versions of their code examples.